# mongo module is loaded but entries not present in php.ini

Tags: php, mongodb

I checked the php.ini which is loaded and it's located at `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

I wanted to edit the `mongo.utf8` parameter but I'm unable to find any mongo entries apart from the `extension=mongo.so` that I've added.

Help in any form is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for a mongo.ini in your PHP extensions folder

Comment: I had checked that. It only has extension=/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so.

Comment: Ah I misread your question inverted the part about finding the extension line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to add the mongo ini settings manually. they all have defaults, but if you want to override them then you must specify them in the ini file yourself.

See the Mongo Runtime configuration: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php

edit**

I would normally create a separate INI config for each extension being added, and put this in your ini scan dir, as labelled on `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the extensions folder (e.g. /etc/php5/conf.d/ on Ubuntu) for a mongo.ini file. If the file doesn't exists you can easily create your own and add the configuration in it. If you don't want to create a separate configuration file you can add it to your php.ini

That being said, you should consider not using that option because as it's noted in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.utf8) it will be removed from future versions:

> This option will be eliminated and exceptions always thrown for
>   non-UTF8 strings starting with version 1.1.0.